# Angular 2 Checkbox Validations Class

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-inputs

I have an checkbox input type inside of a formGroup with Validators.required set. The problem is when i make a click on the checkbox validations class ng-untouched is not changint into ng-touched. How can i fix this problem ?

Thank's

Comment: Do you have some code to show maybe?

Answer (score 0):

ng-touched only shows up after the input is no longer in focus. So check the checkbox, and then then click somewhere else on the screen after. Does that fix it?

Comment: Nope, nothing changes.